# Is there a standard way to check at compile time that file is being preprocessed only?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c11, c17

Context: all the compilers except `__MY_CC__` are not supported. However, how to permit only preprocessing with a 3rd-party compiler?

```
#if     cc -E
/* permit only preprocessing with a 3rd-party compiler */
#elif   ! __MY_CC__
#error  unsupported compiler
#endif
```

UPD. The underlying problem I'm trying to solve:

1. Consider source file named `t0.c`.
2. Requirements for `t0.c`:

   a. `t0.c` is permitted to be compiled using only `my_cc` compiler. No other compiler is supported (because `t0.c` contains target-specific code).

   b. `t0.c` contains some meta information as well. The meta information is available after `t0.c` was preprocessed.

   c. The meta information will be used in an environment which does not have `my_cc` compiler. (It means that `t0.c` is designed not only to be compiled, but to be just preprocessed, i.e. w/o execution of the subsequent translation phases.) So, `t0.c` needs to be permitted to be preprocessed using any conforming implementation (hereafter called `cc`), which is not `my_cc`.
3. How to satisfy such requirements?

User Paul Hankin proposed the following approach:

```
#if   ! __MY_CC__
"compiler not supported"
#endif
```

This code:

1. Will be compiled with `my_cc`. Good.
2. Will not be compiled with `cc`, because of syntax error (ex. is given for clang):

```
t0.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
"compiler not supported"
^
1 error generated.
```

Good.

3. After being preprocessed using `cc -E` the resulting translation unit will contain `"compiler not supported"`, which is undesirable, because:

   a. It is expected that the translation unit does not contain any additional overhead (such as strings).

   b. It breaks the requirements: the `cc -E` *is* supported.

Not good.

We can change the `"compiler not supported"` to `"compilation using non __MY_CC__ is not supported"`. However, it is expected that after `t0.c` was prepossessed the resulting translation unit does not contain any additional overhead (such as strings). Is there any overhead-less solution?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking: can you explain (perhaps give examples) of what you want to allow and what you want to disallow?

Comment: I think you're saying that you want to allow any compiler to preprocess the file, but only allow compilation with your own compiler (which defines `__MY_CC__`). Perhaps you can do  that by adding something that allows preprocessing to continue, but doesn't compile if `__MY_CC__` isn't defined. For example: `#if ! __MY_CC__ "compiler not supported" #endif`

Comment: @PaulHankin Interesting approach, thanks!

Comment: @PaulHankin `#if ! __MY_CC__` then after `cc -E` the preprocessing translation unit is expected to not contain `compiler not supported` (because `cc -E` _is_ supported). Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: There is no portable way.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps you can add the underlying problem you're trying to solve and concrete examples of what you want to allow and disallow in the question?

Comment: "`cc -E` is supported" doesn't mean much. What specific use do you have for allowing a file to be preprocessed by an arbitrary compiler but not compiled by it? Why do you want to restrict compilation to _`_MY_CC__`? What are the actual constraints you are under?

Comment: @PaulHankin Added UPD.

Comment: Would it be cheating to define `__MY_CC__` for other compilers via. command line options if/when they're being used to preprocess only (e.g. the `-D__MY_CC__ -E` command line options for clang, gcc, etc); or to introduce another macro (e.g. `#ifdef PREPROCESSING`) and use `-DPREPROCESSING -E` command line options for all compilers when they're preprocessing?

Comment: To me it looks like the cleanest solution is to add some intermediate meta stage, e.g. the way QT does it. Also Python and libclang seem to be handy here. Not sure if that is going to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132250/4885321

Comment: @Brendan The `-D__MY_CC__ -E` approach looks good (here it is not cheating). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to request "preprocessor-only" compilation. In fact, there is no standard definition of what "preprocessor-only" compilation might do, since the standard (a) does not mandate that preprocessing be a separable module of the compiler and (b) to the extent that the preprocessor phases are defined, mandates that the result after preprocessing phase be a sequence of tokens without whitespace, which is not the same thing as a sequence of characters.

That being the case, there is certainly no standard way to detect whether a given compiler is doing something non-standard, like fabricating a preprocessed output.

If you're not actually concerned with 100% portability, you could probably do this most easily with a build script.