# How to check the state of #pragma STDC?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, pragma

Consider this code:

```
/* t0.c */
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#include "t0.h"
```

Then in `t0.h` how to check the state of `STDC FENV_ACCESS`?

```
/* t0.h */
/* how to check the state of STDC FENV_ACCESS? */
/* something like: #if STDC FENV_ACCESS == ON */
```

If not possible, then:

1. Why not possible?
2. Will it be useful to add this feature to the C standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) Why not possible?

It is *possible* with a custom `cpp` as rryker's answer mentioned. Otherwise, I would have said "no" because the compiler uses the pragmas and that comes *after* the `cpp` pass/stage.

> (2) Will it be useful to add this feature to the C standard?

No, probably not. For the above mentioned reason.

And, because, drawing a leaf from what is already common (e.g. `autoconf`), we can reverse the problem to get the desired results without changing existing compilers.

Define (e.g.) a `features.h`:

```
#ifdef STDC_FENV_ACCESS_ON
#if STDC_FENV_ACCESS_ON
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS OFF
#endif
#endif
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Re: "custom cpp as rryker's answer mentioned": hm, where is the rryker's answer? I don't see it. –
> pmor

I wrote that *before* rryker deleted his answer [partly] because of critique/comments from HolyBlackCat that couldn't be addressed immediately. *My* inference was rryker would be able to improve his answer and undelete it, so I left up the reference.

The link rryker based his answer on was specific extensions provided by `clang`: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html The features that rryker's answer referred to were: the `__has_feature` and `__has_extension` macros [since version 10].

That's the reference. However, with a bit of conjecture on my part, I'll try to summarize.

IIRC, clang's `cpp` is *not* a separate program that is only loosely connected to the compiler [e.g. like it is with `gcc`].

With `clang`, the preprocessor is a [more] tightly integrated stage within the compiler itself. My *presumption* is that this was [initially] done for speed and code reuse.

But, as a "side effect" of that:

1. clang's `cpp` can have much more intimate knowledge of the compiler's inner workings.
2. And, if it's more efficient/desirable, clang's `cpp` stage could also do more of the early (e.g.) `pragma` processing.
3. And, cpp could have access to (e.g.) all the `-f*` arguments/options the compiler sees.
4. So, it has all of the tools that make `#if/#ifdef` on the above `__has_*` macros feasible.

Comment: Re: "custom cpp as rryker's answer mentioned": hm, where is the rryker's answer? I don't see it.

Comment: @pmor He deleted his clang-specific answer, referring to mine as more general :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, and if `t0.c` is actually under your control, you may define appropriate macros whenever a #pragma is used.

```
/* t0.c */
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#define PRAG_FENV_ACCESS_ON
#include "t0.h"
```

This works independently of toolchain vendor. It's a variation of the same theme used to check the presence of `typedef`s in the preprocessor.

Comment: Re: "variation of the same theme": where can I read more on this?

Comment: @pmor Likely in your system headers. E.g. on FreeBSD, there are macros such as `_RSIZE_T_DEFINED`, next to the `typedef mumble rsize_t`.

Comment: FYI: reminds me somehow of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599973/is-there-a-standard-way-to-check-at-compile-time-that-file-is-being-preprocessed), which maybe somehow related / useful.